# Swift UI: How to know if the value of number field is empty or is not a number

Tags: swift, swiftui

My code:

```
struct temp: View {
    @ObservedObject var textValidator = TextValidator()
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            VStack {             
                TextField("Fixed amount", value: $textValidator.amount, format: .number)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                Button("Press") {
                    print(textValidator.amount)   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

class TextValidator: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var amount: Double = 0
}
```

From the code above, when the field is empty or is not a number, the value of `textValidator.amount` is the previous number value.

Example
Round I: the field shows 20 -> textValidator.amount = 20 /
Round II: the field is empty -> textValidator.amount = 2.0

How can I know when the value of `textValidator.amount` is empty or is not a number?